# making a class apply to only category pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

The following class I need to only work on archive (category) pages.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {width:78.5%!important; padding:10% 10% 10% 10%;}
```

If I add it like that it makes other pages go wrong (they need to be 100%). I only want it to work on pages where the body has a class of "archive" (amongst other things - but thats the main difference between the pages where I do want it and don't - I hope I'm explaining this well!)

So I tried

```
.archive .woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {width:78.5%!important; padding:10% 10% 10% 10%;}
```

But this does nothing at all - it effect neither page.

I'm sure there is a simple mistake I'm making - I'm just not sure what it might be. I'm also not sure what other information would be useful to post here to help, but I'll be keeping a close eye on the page - so let me know!

Thanks so much

Here's some of the HTML (for 1 list item):

```
<ul class="products">
<li class="post-134 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first one_fourth entry post-inner shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-tedbaker instock">
<a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop//tedbaker/test-product-copy">
<img width="220" height="165" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TedBaker_TravelDocHolderCoral_5-220x165.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="TedBaker_TravelDocHolderCoral_5">
<h3>Test Product (Copy)</h3>
<span class="price"><span class="amount">£10.00</span></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In your body, do you have the class .archive? If so, try start width body.archive ....

Comment: is `.woocommerce` a body class too?

Comment: "archive" is a class of the body, but body.archive does not make a difference I'm afraid.

Comment: .woocommerce is a body class too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm also not sure what other information would be useful to post here to help..

The HTML would be really useful.

**OT**

> This is not directly related to your question, but as good CSS
>   practice, try to avoid using too much specificity, unless you really
>   don't have any other option.

Comment: I've added so of the html - let me know if more would be helpful. As it's wordpress I can't directly edit the HTML

Comment: ok, since .woocommerce is a body class too, you should place no space between .archive and .woocommerce

Comment: GREAT!!! Thanks Enrico, taking out the space did it. Slowly, I am beginning to get to grips with classes!